# When Joining Tables, If I pass Object I get result but null when passing ViewModel

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, asp.net-core

at the moment I have 2 models, 1 called Customer and 1 called ContactDetails as shown below

```
    // Customer Model
    public class CustomerDto
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    // Customer Contact Details
    public class ContactdetailsDto
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }
```

And A ViewModel as shown below

```
    public class CustomersViewModel
    {
        public CustomerDto? CustomerDto { get; set; }
        public List<CustomerContactDetailsDto>? CustomerContactDetailsDto { get; set; }
    }
```

and I am trying to query the database to get every related customer => ContactDetails but I have a problem.

If I use the below query

```
List<CustomersViewModel> customerData = await Task.FromResult(dapper.GetAll<CustomersViewModel >($"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Customer] LEFT JOIN [Customer].[ContactDetails] ON [dbo].[Customer].[CompanyID] = [Customer].[ContactDetails].[CompanyID] WHERE [dbo].[Customer].[CompanyID] = '{companyID}'", null, commandType: CommandType.Text));
```

the result is null for each Model

but If I change the ViewModel to Object I get a result: Name => Value, I am not sure what's wrong here!

I even tried to Select only the name from each table instead of select all but it didn't work

I have tried this query on the SQL studio and I did work, so I guess the problem here is the view model itself (some data is not matching I guess)

Hope this description is enough for you to help.

Thanks

Comment: You are using Dapper, yet still using string concatenation for parameters. Do not use string concatenation to create an SQL command. Use parameterized statements. See [why it's a bad idea and how to fix it](//bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this is my first time using Dapper

Comment: So was the problem resolved? Is there any further concern do you have?

Comment: the suggestion up regarding the use of Dynamic Parameters (as Dapper support it) instead of passing the parameters directly inside the query.

I will be using Stored procedures so I will be using the Dynamic parameters anyway but the actual problem is not solved yet.

Comment: @MidzElwekil Are `testingViewModel` and `CustomerDataViewModel` same classes or different ones?

Comment: they are both the same, I have edited this and found solution for this issue, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Turned out to be impossible to bind this query to the view model because the query return the result as combined result so binding them to either CustomerDto or ContactDetailsDto is impossible.

to fix this issue I had to return result list from the first table (customer) and then query the second table (contact details) and use viewModel.Add(new ViewModel(){ // bind the models here}.